# Create a list with values from 1 to 'n' without a for-loop

Tags: java, list, function, java-8

I have this function that receives an integer as a param. Its purpose is to return the sum of all the even numbers squared of a list.

For example, if **n = 7** -> returns 56.

```
private static int myFunction (int n) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

        return list.stream().filter( x -> x % 2 == 0)  //Even numbers
                            .map(x -> x * x)           //Squared  
                            .reduce(0, (x,y) -> x + y);//Sum 
}
```

What I would like to do, without a *for-loop*, is to have something like this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,...,n);
```

As an example in Haskell you can create a list from 1 to n with this ' **..** ' :

```
listToN :: Int -> [Int]
listToN n = [1 .. n]
```

Returns: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` if `n == 7`

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1,7)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for `IntStream.rangeClosed(1,7)`.

And btw don't use `reduce` if there is a dedicate method for that (which does exactly what you do via `reduce`)

```
IntStream.range(1, n)
            .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
            .map(x -> x * x)
            .sum();
```

Comment: Simpler and faster: `IntStream.range(0, (n+1)/2) .map(x -> 4 * x * x) .sum()` or potentially even faster: `4 * IntStream.range(0, (n+1)/2) .map(x -> x * x) .sum()`

Comment: @Holger :) indeed